# Mostrar calificación con Estrellas

Tags: php, html, css

Muestro una tabla y en un campo muestro la calificación en entero del 1 al 5 y quisiera mostrarlo atreves de estrellas.
Esta es mi tabla:

```
<tr colspan="6" data-toggle="collapse"data-target="#demo_' . $key . '" class="accordion-toggle">
<td>' . ($key + 1) . ' </td>
<td>' . $row["NombreEtrenado"] . ' ' . $row["ApellidosEntrenado"] . '</td>
<td>' . $row["telefono"] . '</td>
<td>' . $row["finicio"] . ' <--> ' . $row["ffin"] . '</td>
<td>' . $row["evaluacionFinal"] . '</td>';
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Quisiera mostrar estrellas estaticas de esta forma. Ayuda
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes tener seis imágenes diferentes con cero,una, dos... cinco estrellas, nombrarlas de forma conveniente y usar la que corresponda con la evaluación final dentro del `td`. O puedes tener una imagen de estrella amarilla y otra de estrella gris, pintar N amarillas y completar el resto con gris hasta 5. O puedes usar los unicode de estrella blanca y estrella negra y pintarlos ahí.

Comment: O puedes crear una estrella con html y css

Comment: usas algun biblioteca como fontawesome y bootstrap???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes aprovechar el valor de `$row['evaluacionFinal']` como medida para tus calificaciones con la ayuda de `SCSS`:

Solo tienes que modificar el valor de la variable `--rating`.

```html
<div class="stars" style="--rating: 3"></div>
```

Básicamente, sustituyes la extensión `.css` por `.scss`.

```
.stars {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif; // asegura que ★ se muestre correctamente
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1;
  --percent: calc(var(--rating) / 5 * 100%)
}

.stars::before {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fc0 var(--percent), #eee var(--percent));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  content: '★★★★★';
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent
}
```

Aquí [tienes una vista previa](https://codepen.io/8ortiz4/pen/oNBbJrd) desde *codepen.io*.